# Аутентификация в WinForms через WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть WinForms приложение.

Для доступа к определенным элементам интерфейса должны быть соответствующие права.

При первом открытии приложения я считываю их из WCF-службы и на основании этого перевожу элементы в состояние недоступно.

А что мне делать, если во время сеанса работы у пользователя поменяются права?

То что было ранее доступно теперь недоступно или наоборот.

У меня была идея повесить событие по таймеру на главную форму и N- минут проверять права.

Права хранятся в SQL Server, а WCF их считывает по логину.

На сколько правильна такая реализация и нет ли способа лучше?

Comment: Вообще обычно так и делают: права считываются один раз на старте приложения. Если после этого админ что-то поменял, и хочется получить новую функциональность, приложение просто перезапускается.

Comment: Можно проверять права при каждом использовании элемента интерфейса. Например, при нажатии на кнопку сперва идёт проверка прав. Тогда не нужен таймер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда проще на стороне службы из контекстов операций выдирать логины и проверять. Если прав нет, то кидать исключения